# Does the Metaio SDK restricts the overlayed movie resolution?

Tags: video, sdk, overlay, augmented-reality

I am interested in overlaying a high-quality video (stored locally on my phone) on my image target and am wondering if there are software limitations to how large the video resolution can be using the Metaio SDK.

Metaio's recommendation is to use 176x144 20 fps but I am interested in much higher resolutions (720p or even 1080p @ 30 fps).

I realize that there may also very well be hardware limitations if my device is not fast enough to handle the tracking and video rendering, but this isn't my concern currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metaio SDK does not restrict movie texture resolution. It is limited by device capabilities only.